# How to make work Gradle and Maven completely offline?

Tags: maven, gradle

I have a task: to build several Java libraries using Gradle and Maven COMPLETELY OFFLINE!!! This is very strange task, I know, and I need to download all required dependencies and store it on disk before building the projects. How to force gradle and maven to do so? How to set the specific directory for dependencies? Everything should run under Linux + JDK 11. Could you help me, please?
Thank you!

Comment: Build once and safe `$HOME/.m2/repository` for Maven...

Comment: What do you mean by "completely offline"? At some point Maven needs to download the dependencies. After that, you work offline. Realistically cannot download the dependencies manually without Maven unless you are willing to spent several days on figuring them out.

Comment: @khmarbaise for now I have a mess there, relater to several projects

Answer (score 0):

Run `mvn dependency:go-offline` in each of your maven projects.

You set the repo path with `-Dmaven.repo.local=/path/to/repo`.  You can set it in the environment with

```
MAVEN_OPTS=-Dmaven.repo.local=/path/to/repo
```

Comment: How to control a directory (./m2) which is used for dependencies? Is there any settings for set it up to ./libs dir?

Comment: Updated answer above.

Comment: and there should be the same folders structure inside /path/to/repo as in ~/.m2 ?

Comment: Yes.  If your goal is to copy the JARs for your application, use [`dependency:copy-dependencies`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) in your POM to copy from the repo to your build lib.

Comment: it fails with following error: plugin:3.1.1:resolve-plugins (resolve-plugins) on project jackson-databind: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:0 at specified path /home/katya/java/../lib/tools.jar -> [Help 1]
in the same time "mvn install" does work

Comment: what if I simply do "mvn install" than copy ~/.m2 directory to offline machine to build there?

Comment: That might work but `mvn dependency:go-offline` is designed specifically to download *all* dependencies (including those downloaded for `install`).

Comment: tools.jar is an artifact of JDK8 and before and is not part of JDK11.  To compile your project with JDK11, you'll need at a minimum to remove that dependency from your POM(s).  There may be other dependencies you'll need to adjust.

Comment: I still see no need of using mvn dependency:go-offline since the simple copy of ~/.m2 works offline. Is there special need to use "mvn dependency:go-offline" ?